# Uncertainity band in Neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, prediction-interval, uncertainty

I am working on a problem where I have to give the uncertainty band of my predictions like the image attached.

[image]

I have seen a [StackExchange solution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/472032/confidence-and-prediction-intervals-for-nonlinear-models/472050#472050) for this, but in the solution code, we are using the true output(y) to calculate the noise, which is then used to plot the uncertainty. Is it possible to plot an uncertainty band like the image attached, without using the true output? If yes, can someone please put a sample code?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solutions are bootstrapping (generically applicable to many settings), various Bayesian neural network approaches (e.g. Monte-Carlo drop-out = training a neural network with drop-out and then leaving drop-out on during inference to get varying results) and fitting a neural network that predicts e.g. the 2.5th, 50th and 97.5th percentile of the predictive distribution (i.e. quantile regression - there's a few useful tricks on can use to enforce an appropriate ordering of the quantiles, see e.g. [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/osic-pulmonary-fibrosis-progression/discussion/182737)). A number of Kaggle competitions have involved providing good prediction intervals and looking at how people solved this issue when using neural networks is worthwhile (see e.g. [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/osic-pulmonary-fibrosis-progression/discussion/181632#1004612) or [here](https://www.kaggle.com/ulrich07/quantile-regression-with-keras))

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer and the links.